# How to get a layer object from a geometry

Tags: python, gdal

I have a polygon as a gdal geometry and I'd like to use it with  `gdal.RasterizeLayer()`. As its name states, this method needs a layer object, not a geometry. So I need to convert/wrap my geometry into a layer object.

The only way I got this to work is by exporting the geometry as GeoJSON and opening that with the GeoJSON driver as datasource:

```
GeoJSONdriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('GeoJSON')
ds = GeoJSONdriver.Open(my_polygon_geometry.ExportToJson())

layer = ds.GetLayer(0)
```

This feels very clumsy and since I also need to look out for performance I was wondering if there is a more direct approach to make that conversion?